# Getting Velocity from Array of Acceleration Data over Time

Tags: integration

I have an accelerometer, measuring acceleration in G over a given time frame.
I am trying to convert this acceleration into velocity time domain data.

I am from an IT background, and am trying to develop a method to do this programatically. I would like to be able to make some sort of loop and process each row and insert it into a new array that represetns the velocity time domain data.

I am having trouble converting the mathmatics into something I can understand on the programming side.

Here is the start of my Acceleration Time Domain data...
time(ms) , x_axis(G)
(1.25, -0.8539)
(2.5 , 0)
(3.75, -0.1574)
(5   , -0.06744)

This is on a motor, so assuming the initial velocity is 0 might be faulty, but I don't have a better guess than that.
If I use an equation of a = (v0 - v1) / (t0 - t1) and solve for v0, I don't seem to get the right answer.

If I run this data through tools that integrate this data for me, I *think* I should be getting these answers for the Velocity:

(1.25, -206)
(2.5 , -206)
(3.75, -282)
(5   , -314.5)

I've tried to make sure I convert G to in/sec² , and convert my ms to s, and keep my units in line and it changes cancels out to in/sec, but like I mentioned above, it doesnt seem to match.

Here is some of my work using the first values:

-0.8539G = V-0/1.25ms    (solving for V)
-329.681 in/sec² = V / .00125s    (multiple both sides times .00125s)
-.4121 = V

That -.4121 doesnt seem to match the -206 I should be getting.

Another example from further along in the array:

-0.1574G = (-206 - V) / .00125s    (convert G to in/sec²)
-60.770 in/sec² = (-206 - V) / .00125s   (multiple both sides times .00125s)
-.0759635 in/sec² = -206 - V  (add 206 to both sides)
205.92 = -V

-205.92 = V  (but I think I should have gotten -282)

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the data looks, assume that you start with $v(t_0=0)=0$ and $a_0=0$. Then you accelerate with $a_1$ between $(t_1+t_0)/2$ and $(t_2+t_1)/2$. Then at $t_1$ the velocity will be $v_1=a_1t_1/2$. I also see the velocity is in in/ms. So for your calculation for $v_1$, you need to divide by $2$ and multiply by $1000$.
The final formula seems to be (up to some conversion factors) $$v_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\frac12a_n(t_n-t_{n-1})$$

Comment: Thank you for answering!

So my time is 1.25ms in between each data point.

So working the first data point, using this phrase:
Then at t1 the velocity will be v1=a1t1/2.

v(1) = (-329.681 * 1.25 ) /2        does equal -206 !

However, then if I divide by 2 and multiple by 1000, I end up with -103025.

I think I am missing something obvious in understanding the integrals or the calculations here.

The velocity would be additive, you retain the velocity from the previous calculation, which is where I think the integral comes in?

Comment: You got v=-.4121. If you divide by 2, you get 0.206. Multiply by 1000, and get 206